# How to keep a model datas if !ModelState.IsValid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, modelstate

I'm a beginner in MVC so I apologize for the newb question :

I want to keep my model datas if the user don't fill the form correctly.

[image: POST code in controller]

Is there a way to keep the data from `res` when I return `View(res)`?

Thanks for your help

EDIT :

NewReservationVM class :

```
public class NewReservationVM
{
    int idRoom;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    DateTime checkin;
    DateTime checkout;
    decimal price;

    public int IdRoom { get => idRoom; set => idRoom = value; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Veuillez saisir votre prénom.")]
    public string FirstName { get => firstName; set => firstName = value; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Veuillez saisir votre nom.")]
    public string LastName { get => lastName; set => lastName = value; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Checkin { get => checkin; set => checkin = value; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Checkout { get => checkout; set => checkout = value; }
    public decimal Price { get => price; set => price = value; }
}
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(NewReservationVM res)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
            return RedirectToAction("ResOk", res);

        return View(res);
    }
```

Comment: Could you write your view model "NewReservationVM" completely?

Comment: You shouldn't be loosing values on the res instance... Please, post more code cause probably the problem isn't what you think it is...

Comment: Suggestion: Put a breakpoint on the first line of that controller method and use the "quickwatch" to inspect the values received on the "res" variable. If the values are there, when you call "return View(res);" you're indeed providing all the received values back to the view (it doesn't matter if your model is or isn't valid).

Comment: It actually get the initial values, because I retrieve them in my "ResOk" view if the ModelState.IsValid return true. My problem is that I lose them only if the ModelState.IsValid is false. It should return the exact same view, but i lose datas for some reason.

Comment: If you are using the built in html/tag -helper in your view then your values should be preserved. Could you also post your razor view?

Comment: Use unobstructive javascripts for validations and in your case I guess the data should be their just the password might be missing

Comment: `RedirectiToACtion("ResOk", res)` [doesn't do what you think it does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RedirectToAction%28System.String,System.Object%29).

Answer (score -1):

I've change your ViewModel class to this:

```
public int IdRoom { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Veuillez saisir votre prénom.")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Veuillez saisir votre nom.")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime Checkin { get; set; }
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime Checkout { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Now it's working as you want. In addition, if you want to use private fields and implement set and set methods, the proper is like that:

```
private int idRoom;
public int IdRoom
{
  get { return idRoom; }
  set { idRoom = value; }
}
```

I'm not familiar with the syntax you've used, but this one is the most standard as I know and it's working.